# PDF of Jakes' Model $\cos(\theta)$

Tags: bessel-functions

If we have an angle $\theta$ follows a uniformly distribution $[-\pi,\pi]$, the PDF of $\theta$ will be $p(\theta)=\frac{1}{\pi-(-\pi)}$ in $[-\pi,\pi]$, if we consider the Jakes' model $f=f_{\max}\cos(\theta)$, where $f_{\max}$ is just a constant. what will be the PDF $p(f)$ of this Jakes' model? I guess we might need the Bessel function.

Comment: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/0470847808.app1

Comment: Thank you !!!! This really helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

*Is there a mistake here?  I didn't use the Bessel function.*

So $p(\theta)=1/(2\pi)$, constant.  For the CDF $F_f$ of $f = f_{\rm max}\cos(\theta)$, let's assume $f_{\rm max}$ is positive.  Note $\cos$ is increasing on $[-\pi,0]$ and decreasing on $[0,\pi]$.

The values of $f$ are in $[-f_{\rm max},f_{\rm max}]$.  If $t<-f_{\rm max}$, then $F_f(t)=0$.
If $t>f_{\rm max}$, then $F_f(t) = 1$.

For $-f_{\rm max}\le t \le f_{\rm max}$,
\begin{align}
F_f(t) &= \mathbb P[f \le t] = \mathbb P[f_{\rm max}\cos\theta \le t]
=\mathbb P\big[\cos\theta \le \frac{t}{f_{\rm max}}\big]
\\
&=\mathbb P\left[\theta \ge \arccos \frac{t}{f_{\rm max}}\right]
+\left[\theta \le -\arccos \frac{t}{f_{\rm max}}\right]
=2\mathbb P\left[\theta \ge \arccos \frac{t}{f_{\rm max}}\right]
\\
&=\frac{2}{2\pi}\left(\pi - \arccos \frac{t}{f_{\rm max}}\right)
= 1 - \frac{1}{\pi}\arccos \frac{t}{f_{\rm max}}
= \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{\pi}\arcsin\frac{t}{f_{\rm max}}
\end{align}
So this CDF is merely a rearrangement of the arccsin graph.
See [arcsine distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcsine_distribution)

Then the PDF is the derivative of this,
$$
p_f(t) = \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{f_{\rm max}^2-t^2}}
$$

Comment: thank you! you are right, really appreciate that!!

Comment: I find the CDF, which is the integral of the PDF in the reference of Aaron.